# Realtime database query and react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm quite new to performing firebase realtime database queries and react native. I have a list of users in my realtime database and some of the users have a list of properties as shown below. I would like to obtain these properties as well as the users of the properties and place it into an array using react native. I'm not to sure how to do this.

This is what I have so far:

```
  database().ref(`users/`).once(`value`, snapshot =>{
       snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            if(childSnapshot.val().properties != null) { 
                                              
            }                                                      
  });
```

I would like the error to be displayed as:

[{uid1,property1}, {uid1,property2}, {uid2,property1}, {uid2,property2}, {uid2,property3},...., {uidX,propertyX}]

[image]})

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to dig into the `childSnapshot` object to see nested data?

Comment: Yes, I see that childSnapshot.val().properties gives me the properties but I'm not sure how to push it into an array like [{uid1,property1}, {uid1,property2}, {uid2,property1}, {uid2,property2}, {uid2,property3},...., {uidX,propertyX}]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I find that in cases like this, it really helps to give your variables good names:

```
database().ref(`users/`).once(`value`, snapshot =>{
  let properties = [];
  snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
    if (userSnapshot.hasChild("properties")) { 
      userSnapshot.child("properties").forEach((propertySnapshot) => {
        properties.push({ 
          uid: userSnapshot.key,
          property: propertySnapshot.val() 
        })
      })
    }                                                      
  });
  console.log(properties);
});
```